# Remove special character in the description column DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am using regular expressions on a DataFrame. My expression matches lines like: [*, *,___,"
"] as you can see in this description:

```
df["Description"].str.extract("Localisation[\s]*:.*\n([^_\n]*)\n").value_counts()
```

[image]

How can I modify my expressions to remove those lines?

Comment: Are you talking about the asterisk (`*`)?  It would be great if you could put up one or two lines before running your regular expression.

Comment: This is not clear: what do you want to match? Which lines do you *want* to extract?

Comment: Do you need more help with this?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
df["Description"] = df["Description"].apply(lamda x: ''.join([s for s in x if s.isalnum() or s.isspace()]))
```

Or if you want to remove only specific values:

```
values = ["*", "_"," "]
df["Description"] = df["Description"].apply(lamda x: ''.join([s for s in x if x not in values]))
```

Comment: I try this map(lambda x:x if x not in values,df["Description"].str.extract(r"Localisation[\s]*:.*\n([^_\n]*)\n"))

Comment: I have erroe message: File "<ipython-input-93-c15e1e51adc1>", line 37
    map(lambda x:x if x not in values,df["Description"].str.extract(r"Localisation[\s]*:.*\n([^_\n]*)\n"))
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax